# How does someone monitor web API access rate limit?

Tags: api, authentication, monitoring

I was just wondering how do people manage access to their JSON or other type of APIs. Is there a tool to manage rate limit such as an IP address is allows to access the API 60 times per second.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at http://www.webservius.com - it's currently free for low-call-volume APIs